# making a div show/hide with different triggers - jquery

Tags: jquery

This is probably a simple enough question (specially for the JQuery gurus) but is eluding me.

I am loading a form remotely from another page using jQuery.support.cors function when the user clicks the Login/Register hyperlink and a toggleClass function to show and hide the load. That part works. My issue is, I need the div that contains the form to hide also when the user clicks anywhere else on the page.

p.s. (the form must not show on hover, this is an all click functionality)

This is my modified code (basically because I can't do support.cors in a fiddle or code.pen

```
<li class="retrodropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
   <a href="#">Sign In / Register</a>
   <div class="retrodropdown-menu">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <div class="login-form">
               SHOW AND HIDE          
            </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</li>
```

This is my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('.retrodropdown a').click(function () {
      $(this).siblings('.retrodropdown-menu').toggleClass('block', 'hidden');
   });

   $('html').click(function () {
      $(this).find('.retrodropdown-menu').hide();
   })
});
```

Here is a [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYXdXa)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPYzoz

basically you catch the main click event on the document, then check if the click was outside the form. If so, you hide it, and don't forget to stopPtopagation on the click event that shows it or else it will trigger the document click again, which will hide it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      $('.retrodropdown a').click(function (event) {
           $('.retrodropdown-menu').toggle();
           event.stopPropagation();
           event.preventDefault();
           return;
      });

      $(document).on('click',function (event) {           
        if(!$(event.target).closest('.retrodropdown-menu').length) {               
                if($('.retrodropdown-menu').is(":visible")) {                
                    $('.retrodropdown-menu').hide()
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
            }    
      })
    });
```

Comment: Nice job! Except, it now doesn't toggle on the hyperlink. But it's a good start!

Comment: just change the show() to toggle(). edited the code pen and answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('.retrodropdown a').click(function () {
      $(this).siblings('.retrodropdown-menu').show();
   });

   $('html').click(function () {
      $(this).find('.retrodropdown-menu').hide();
   })
});
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do, Can you brief it.?

Comment: I thought I did in my question. I need the div that contains the form (.retrodropdown-menu) to toggle between show and hide on the click of the Login/Register link (retrodropdown a) but, I also need it to hide when the user clicks anywhere else on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    $(this).find('.retrodropdown-menu').hide();
});
```

Comment: no sir. didin't work in the codepen or my application